# Cannot declare React context in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

i am trying to make a context with hooks in react in typescript like this:

```
interface SettingsStateContextProps {
  sort: string;
  type: string;
  price: string;
  option_full: boolean;
  option_rated: boolean;
  option_free: boolean;
}

export const SettingsStateContext = React.createContext<
  Partial<SettingsStateContextProps>
>({});

export const SettingsStoreProvider:any = ({ reducer, initialState, children }):any => (
  <SettingsStateContext.Provider // ERROR HERE
    value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}
    children={children}
  />
);
```

but for some reason i don't know why I cannot declare SettingsStateContext.Provider? I am getting an error message with

> 'Cannot find namespace 'SettingsStateContext'

How do i fix this?

Comment: Is the file having the extension `tsx`?

Comment: no, changing to .tsx worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your second export. There is how i use it:

1) Export your context to use it anywhere

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'

// this is needed so that components using theme will see it's type
declare module 'styled-components' {
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}

interface Theme {
  color: string
}

const defaultTheme = { color: 'red' }

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext<Partial<Theme>>({})

export const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>(defaultTheme)

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme }}>
          {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

2) Wrap component where you want to get theme access (i use it one time at top level of app):

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeContextProvider, Input } from '@frontend'

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeContextProvider>
        <Input />
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Use it in component (example for shared component):

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

type MyProps = {
  err?: boolean
}

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, MyProps>(({ err, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
})

const StyledInput = styled.input<MyProps>`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px ${({ err, theme }) => (err ? theme.badColor : theme.primaryColor)};
  border-radius: 5px;
`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seein' here you didn't put any square bracket after `React.createContent`, you should put write like this `React.createContext()`,

```
export const SettingsStateContext = React.createContext();
```

put your logic in squre bracket, I should work!

you can study [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to learn more about!

Thanks!

Comment: With Partial there is no need to put anything in brackets.

Comment: I don't have clue about Partial!

Comment: you can read about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html