# What are the right types for a useContext with TypeScript/ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, createcontext

I am refactoring to `TypeScript` a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTeuhbP7wdE) in `ReactJS` that I am following. For the most part, the tutorial teaches you how to refactor most of the code as bonus material. However the log-in part is done in `ReactJS/JavaScript` only and I tried to refactor my code as a way to challenge myself. The part I am stuck on is `createContext` as I am not able to understand the types needed.

### Original JS code

**JS code - Context/Provider**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";


export const Context = createContext();

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, setState]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    )
};

export default UserProvider;
```

On the Login component it gets called with `const [_user, setUser] = useContext(Context);`

### My attempt

**What I've tried**

I tried to apply the following solutions and I'm not really grasping the concepts well enough to apply them successfully:

- [Cannot declare React context in typescript? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021426/cannot-declare-react-context-in-typescript)
- [Cannot find namespace 'ctx' error when creating Context with react - typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242264/cannot-find-namespace-ctx-error-when-creating-context-with-react-typescript)
- [How to use React Context with TypeScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-context-typescript/#:%7E:text=React%20Context%20allows%20you%20to,that%20need%20to%20consume%20it.)
- [React Context + TypeScript — The Easy Way](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-react-context-with-typescript-the-easy-way-2ed1010f6e84)

**TS code - Context/Provider**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { IUser, UserContextType } from "./@types/context";


export const Context = createContext<UserContextType | undefined>(undefined);

const UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<IUser>();

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    )
};

export default UserProvider;
```

**TS code - types**

```
export interface IUser {
    user: string;
    password: string;
};

export type UserContextType = {
    state: IUser;
    setState: (newSession: IUser) => void;
};
```

**Errors**

```
<Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
```

> Type 'IUser | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUser'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUser'.ts(2322)

```
const [_user, setUser] = useContext(Context);
```

> Type 'UserContextType | undefined' is not an array type.ts(2461)

Comment: The context does not have `state` or `setState` in its type. Did you mean to use those names instead of `sessions` and `saveSession`? Also, since you're passing in an object as the context value, the return value of `useContext` will also be an object (with those properties), not an array (so don't use `[]` brackets)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I edited the code based on what I think you are suggesting. My guess was that there wasn't a direct relationship between the name of the types and the useState variables created. About the brackets [] not sure if you mean only on the useState or overall.

Comment: are the errors still existing, if yes please update your question?

Comment: @AhmedTarek yes they are still existing and I updated the errors themselves.

Comment: I see that the <Context.Provider /> is different in `TS code - Context/Provider` and `Errors` code snippets. I suggest you using what is in `TS code - Context/Provider`

Comment: You're now passing an array as the context value instead of an object here: `value={[state, setState]}` Decide on either an array or an object, then use that schema everywhere

Comment: So for what I'm understanding both @AhmedTarek and @CertainPerformance are referring to `value={{state, setState}}` as the way to do it as an object. When I do it that way `value={{state` still gives me an error that `Type 'IUser | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IUser'.`. I have also removed the array from the type `UserContextType` as was giving me an error with `setState`.I updated everything on the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you declare the context type like so:

```
export const Context = createContext<UserContextType | undefined>(undefined);
```

This means that the `value` of the context is either an object with all properties present of `UserContextType` or it is `undefined`.

Then here:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<IUser>();
```

You create state that has a type of `IUser`. But because you do not provide a default value, the default value is `undefined`. This is added to the state's type for you. So `state` is of type `IUser | undefined`.

Then we get here:

```
value={{state, setState}}
```

`state` is `IUser | undefined`, but the context type expects an `IUser[]` for that property. So neither `IUser` or `undefined` are valid types there.

---

First, you need to make sure that if you are passing in an object, then the object is correctly typed. That means that it has all required properties present. Else, pass in undefined. You can do this with a ternary expression:

```
value={state ? {state, setState} : undefined}
```

Now if state has a value, then the context value is created and passed it. Otherwise the context value is `undefined`.

---

But now you get this error:

```
    Types of property 'state' are incompatible.
      Type 'IUser' is missing the following properties from type 'IUser[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.(2322)
```

This is because you trying to assign a single user `IUser` to an array of users `IUser[]`.

It looks like you mean for the content to only hold a single user, so you probably want to change the contexts type to:

```
export type UserContextType = {
    state: IUser;
    setState: (newSession: IUser) => void;
};
```

Which works, [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZpSqUDCEAdpQB7wC+cAZlBCHABEtdDEEBuAFCSkrSLDjAWSKN3RI4ASQCqxKLklwjBPQC44hGFCUBzKcbhgUhQgHdoAE3OXrTO5I4pGTloeBgATzANXRVGZXYAFUiNAF4DB0sKJHMdPXtjYhgyLPMACiYkVxIkF2BmHJioAEo4FIA+OAA3CGAPKUDpYPl4NGZLODi2eDSaOiRJ2RgAHkaFxOS4AB8CJg8kbiUkDzbS-F39w48moNGmccaABT5O3pVzZFEAOgAxeiWPjCfAEwAByED2HTSpTwaAAFsAADYeWhMOAcFrtdLGW7jADamUo2EKxUoAF1WiZSORKEtcioTtdpA5aDB8FBUaVDA5jEs1jBPk8IC89vpOigEfgkCkcASNAB+XCyolIIrUpBccxnPYHCoeDhtHBwxHIpBMDhLAD0fIFz1eUDaXKMTQCQVkwzg2pQ+AR8EetpFUiAA)

Or you need to pass in an array of users:

```
const UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<IUser[]>([]);

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    )
};
```

Which also works, [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=3&pln=16&pc=1#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)

---

You could also change the context type to:

```
export type UserContextType = {
    state?: IUser;
    setState: (newSession: IUser) => void;
};
```

Which makes `state` optional, and then:

```
const UserProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<IUser>();

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    )
};
```

Should work fine, [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=3&pln=16&pc=1#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)

Comment: I know is not the expected comment of SO but I want to deeply thank you for the effort you have put into showing me this. Not only now works but now I have a much better understanding of `createContext`

Comment: I'll allow it :) You're welcome.

Answer (score -2):

This is an example of a Context on Typescript

`AuthContext.tsx`:

```js
import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { AuthContextData } from "../models/AuthContextData.model";

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextData>({} as AuthContextData);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<object | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  async function signIn(): Promise<void> {
   console.log('sign in')
  }

  async function signOut(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('sign out')
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ signed: !!user, user, signIn, signOut, loading }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  return context;
}
```

`AuthContextData.ts`:

```js
export interface AuthContextData {
  signed: boolean;
  user: object | null;
  signIn(): Promise<void>;
  signOut(): Promise<void>;
  loading: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Not gonna lie, this confuses me a bit more, and rises some questions. How do I type check the input of the user as string? as I'm understanding it is an object or a null. Also How do I access from that object the password or the username?

Comment: That is an example of context, sure. But it doesn't explain why the OP is having problems.